# Optimizing this "coincidence search" algorithm, for speed

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, optimization, micro-optimization

I've written an algorithm, designed to simulate a data produced by an experiment, and then perform a "coincidence search" on that data (more on that in a moment...). The data in question is a `vector<vector<double> >`, with elements picked from a Gaussian distribution (more-or-less, random numbers). Each "column" represents a "data stream", and each row an instant in time. The "location" of each element in the "array" must be preserved.

---

**The Algorithm:**

The algorithm is designed to perform the following task:

Iterate simultaneously through all `n` columns (data streams), and count the number of times at least `c` unique columns have an element with an absolute value greater than some threshold, such that the elements lie in a specified time interval (i.e. a certain number of rows).

When this occurs, we add one to a counter, and then jump forward in time (row-wise) by some specified amount. We start over again, until we've traversed the entire "array". Finally, we return the value of the counter (the "number of coincidences").

---

**My solution:**

I give the code first, then step through it piece-by-piece and explain it's operation (and, also hopefully clarifying some details):

```
size_t numOfCoincidences(vector<vector<double>> array, double value_threshold, size_t num_columns){

    set<size_t> cache;
    size_t coincidence_counter = 0, time_counter = 0;

    auto exceeds_threshold = [&](double element){ return fabs(element) >= value_threshold; };

    for(auto row_itr = begin(array); row_itr != end(row_itr); ++row_itr){

        auto &row = *row_itr;

        auto coln_itr = std::find_if(execution::par_unseq, begin(row), end(row), exceeds_threshold);
        while(coln_itr != row.end()){
            cache.insert(distance(begin(row), coln_itr));
            coln_itr = std::find_if(next(coln_itr), end(row), exceeds_threshold);
        }

        if(size(cache) >= num_columns){

            ++coincidence_counter;
            cache.clear();

            if(distance(row_ctr, end(waveform)) > (4004000 - time_counter)){
                advance(row_ctr, ((4004000 - time_counter)));
            } else {
                return coincidence_counter;
            }

        }


        if(time_counter == time_threshold){
            row_itr -= (time_counter + 1);
            cache.clear();
        }


        ++time_counter;


    }

    if(cache.size() == 0) time_counter = 0;

    return(coincidence_counter);

}
```

---

### *How it works...*

I iterate through the data (`vector<vector<double> > array`) row-wise:

`for(auto row_itr = begin(array); row_itr != end(row_itr); ++row_itr)`

For each row, I use `std::find_if` to get every element exceeding the value threshold (`value_threshold`):

```
        auto coln_itr = std::find_if(execution::par_unseq, begin(row), end(row), exceeds_threshold);
        while(coln_itr != row.end()){
            cache.insert(distance(begin(row), coln_itr));
            coln_itr = std::find_if(next(coln_itr), end(row), exceeds_threshold);
        }
```

What I'm after is the columnar index, so I use `std::distance` to get that and store it in an `std::set`, `cache`. I choose `std::set` here because I'm interested in counting the number of *unique* columns that have a value exceeding `value_threshold`, within some time (i.e., row) interval. By using `std::set`, I can just dump the columnar index of every such value, and duplicates are "automatically removed". Then, later, I can simply check the size of `cache` and, if it's greater than or equal to the specified number (`num_columns`), I've found a "coincidence".

After getting the columnar index of every value exceeding `value_threshold`, I check the size of `cache` to see if I've found enough unique columns. If I have, I add one to the `coincidence_counter`, I clear the `cache`, then jump forward in "time" (i.e., rows) by some specified amount (here, `4004000 - time_counter`). Notice that I subtract `time_counter`, which keeps track of the "time" (# of rows) from the first found value(s) exceeding `value_threshold`. I want to jump forward in time from *that* starting point.

```
        if(size(cache) >= num_columns){

            ++coincidence_counter;
            cache.clear();

            if(distance(row_ctr, end(waveform)) > (4004000 - time_counter)){
                advance(row_ctr, ((4004000 - time_counter)));
            } else {
                return coincidence_counter;
            }

        }
```

Finally, I check `time_counter`. Remember that the `num_columns` unique columns must be within some time (i.e., row) threshold of one another. I start that time count from the first found value exceeding `value_threshold`. If I've exceeded the time threshold, what I want to do is empty `cache()`, and start over using the second-found value exceeding the value threshold (if there is one) as the *new* first-found value, and hopefully find a coincidence using that as the starting point.

Instead of keeping track of the time (i.e., row index) of each found value, I simply start over at one after the first-found value (i.e., `time_counter + 1`).

```
        if(time_counter == time_threshold){
            row_itr -= (time_counter + 1);
            cache.clear();
        }
```

I also add one to `time_counter` with each loop, and set it equal to `0` if `cache` has size `0` (I want to start counting time (i.e., rows) from the first-found value exceeding `value_threshold`).

---

**Attempted Optimizations:**

*I'm not sure if these have helped, hurt, or otherwise, however here's what I've tried (with little success)*

I've replaced all `int` and `unsigned int` with `size_t`. I understand that this *may* be ever so slightly faster, and these values should never be less than `0` anyhow.

I've also used `execution::par_unseq` with `std::find_if`. I'm not sure how much this helps. The "array" typically has about `16-20` columns, but an *exceptionally* large number of rows (on the order of `50000000` or more). Since `std::find_if` is "scanning" individual rows, which only have tens of elements, at most, perhaps parallelization isn't helping much.

---

**Goals:**

Unfortunately, the algorithm takes an exceptionally long time to run. My utmost priority is *speed*. If possible, I'd like to cut the execution time in half.

Some things to keep in mind:
The "array" is typically on the order of `~20` columns by `~50000000` rows (sometimes longer). It has very few `0's`, and cannot be re-arranged (the order of the "rows", and elements in each row, matters). It takes up (unsurprisingly) a *ton* of memory, and my machine is therefore quite resource constrained.

I'm also running this as interpreted `C++`, in `cling`. In my work, I've never used compiled `C++` much. I've tried compiling, however it hasn't helped much. I've also tried playing with compiler optimization flags.

---

What can be done to cut execution time (at the expense of virtually anything else?)

> Please, let me know if I can offer any additional information to assist in answering the question.

Comment: Iput your file in my IDE and tried to compile. There are many syntax erros. Many I could fix. But: what is "time_threshold" and "waveform". Where and how they are defined with what purpose. If you can give me this additional information. I will use a profiler to check, where the speed is lost.

Comment: You might get the required execution speed up by just compiling with -O3.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems like it might be memory bandwidth bound regardless, but I'd try removing the fancy algorithm stuff in favor of a windowed count. Untested C++:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using std::fabs;
using std::size_t;
using std::vector;

size_t NumCoincidences(const vector<vector<double>> &array,
                       double value_threshold, size_t num_columns) {
  static constexpr size_t kWindowSize = 4004000;
  const auto exceeds_threshold = [&](double x) {
    return fabs(x) >= value_threshold;
  };
  size_t start = 0;
  std::vector<size_t> num_exceeds_in_window(array[0].size());
  size_t num_coincidences = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    const auto &row = array[i];
    for (size_t j = 0; j < row.size(); j++) {
      num_exceeds_in_window[j] += exceeds_threshold(row[j]) ? 1 : 0;
    }
    if (i >= start + kWindowSize) {
      const auto &row = array[i - kWindowSize];
      for (size_t j = 0; j < row.size(); j++) {
        num_exceeds_in_window[j] -= exceeds_threshold(row[j]) ? 1 : 0;
      }
    }
    size_t total_exceeds_in_window = 0;
    for (size_t n : num_exceeds_in_window) {
      total_exceeds_in_window += n > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    if (total_exceeds_in_window >= num_columns) {
      start = i + 1;
      std::fill(num_exceeds_in_window.begin(), num_exceeds_in_window.end(), 0);
      num_coincidences++;
    }
  }
  return num_coincidences;
}
```